# Can a equation be represented by more than one graph of different dimensions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the equation $x^2 + y^2 - 0z = 1$ If you only consider the x-y plane, this will trace out the well-known unit circle. However, if you consider 3d space, a cylinder of infinite height without volume is traced out. Does this show that a equation can represent different graphs of different dimensions.

Comment: is that $z_0$ or $(z)(0)$?

Comment: @kmeis - Sorry for the confusion. It is (z)(0)

Comment: @Henrik - Meant Space, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You (typically) can't make an image of an equation in a space of fewer dimensions than the equation has variables. If you just ignore some of the variables, you are looking at the intersection of the graph and the space spanned by those variables.

If you make am image of an equation in a space of more dimensions (which is really what you do, when you add variables with a coefficient of zero) than you have variables, you'll get a (generalised) cylinder, whose cross section is the graph in the "natural" number of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

A few points about the details in this question. First $x^2+y^2−0z=1$ is equivalent to $x^2+y^2=1$ and has no third parameter. Second, x2+y2=0 is not a function as even it we define it as $f(y)$ or $f(x)$ it does not satisfy the definition of a function. However, we can make a function $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}^2$ which will contain all the points of the unit circle. For example $$ f(t) = (cos(t), sin(t))$$ is a function that describes the unit circle.
That is to say that it represents a unit circle and its image (output) only contains the points of a circle, not a cylinder. Functions usually have a defined codomain. A function that describes a unit circle doesn't map to 3d space.

It is important to note that this function doesn't map to $\mathbb{R}^3$ (3d space). In some sense, this function doesn't care about the third dimension.

However, you could have a function that describes an infinite cylinder. The intersection of this cylinder and a plane can describe a unit circle, but it isn't the same function.

I hope this clears some of the confusion up, but if this doesn't make sense please leave a comment.

Comment: I understand your premise kmeis, but what surprises me, which also is my motivation for asking this question, is how adding a variable with a coefficient of zero to a equation could essentially change the way a function is visually represented either though it is algebraically equivalent to the original equation

Comment: Hmm, I think I mean to say that a function whose image is a unit circle and a function whose image is an infinite cylinder are different functions. Adding $0z$ may not be the appropriate step for what you are trying to accomplish though, as it seems a bit nebulous. Since $z$ has no effect, I suppose it could be argued that it could be on any $xy$ plane at a level of $z$, but it doesn't explicitly state that. I think most would interpret that as simply a circle.

Comment: That helped me understand what you were thinking and I've added a section to my answer.

Comment: It's the context that matters here. Viewed as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$, the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ determines a circle. As a subset of $\Bbb R^3$, the same equation determines a cylinder (and to top it all off: The two even agree when z = 0!)